# How to move a github project from local system into Azure Databricks Community?

Tags: migration, databricks

I have the github project on my local machine.

[image]

Please note that I have many files inside my code/data directories.

I would like to move all files into my Databricks Community account. How can I do that?

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You can check-in the code from Local machine to Github and integrate Databricks with Github.

Detailed steps are mentioned in these article's "[Azure Databricks & Version management](https://medium.com/@cprosenjit/azure-databricks-version-management-35fc78e11d7)" and "[GitHub Version Control](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/github-version-control.html)".

Hope this helps.